# Ruby: Begin transaction, rollback transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New in rubies, I'm facing a tiny problem.. need a fresh pair of eyes

fyi: I'm not using scaffold so that I can understand the step by step process of building in ruby.

When I try to add a new gig, it does not save on the database and I see the following error on my server logs...

```html
Started POST "/gigs" for ::1 at 2017-03-06 17:34:34 +0300
Processing by GigsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lDSSVGuQDFlKwdkP8m1Gk4rzA4wG03wzpd5LmA19HZM7LPOLSrDBYGSsRRvwRZTbfVoe/HZmeGxBjRwVnZSKBw==", "gig"=>{"name"=>"Perry Dillard", "budget"=>"500", "duration"=>"4", "startdate"=>"19-Jan-1971", "description"=>"Reprehenderit, eligendi natus consequatur, dicta quae corporis voluptatem, ut pariatur. Consequatur excepteur natus eos, eos cum et eiusmod.", "location"=>"Dicta beatae culpa ut nostrud nihil voluptatem Eum", "open"=>"true", "hired"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"post it"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/gigs
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/gigs" for ::1 at 2017-03-06 17:34:34 +0300
Processing by GigsController#index as HTML
  Rendering gigs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered gigs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 26.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

This is my form

```html
<div class="container">
 <h4 class ="center">Post an Internship Opportunity</h4>
 <br>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
<%= form_for @gig do |f| %>
    
     <div class= "row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control input-lg" %>
        <small class="healer block"> Data entry, writer, receptinist etc </small>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div> 

      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :budget %>
        <%= f.text_field :budget, class: "form-control" %>
        <small class="healer block"> Free or min Kshs 5000 </small>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :duration %>
        <%= f.text_field :duration, class: "form-control" %>
        <small class="healer block"> 2 weeks, 1 month, 3 months </small>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :startdate %>
        <%= f.text_field :startdate, class: "form-control" %>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
        <small class="healer block"> What are the expectations and working hours, mentorship opportunities etc </small>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :location %>
        <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control " %>
        <small class="healer block"> ignore if same location with your registered office </small>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :open %>
        <%= f.text_field :open, class: "form-control" %>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :hired %>
        <%= f.text_field :hired, class: "form-control" %>
       </div><!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
     <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">   <%= f.submit "post it" %> </button>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.col-* -->
```

This is my gig controller

```html
class GigsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  
 end

 def new
  @gig = Gig.new 
 end

 def create
  @gig = Gig.new(gig_params)
  @gig.save
  redirect_to @gig
 end

 
#private stuff
 private

 def gig_params
  params.require(:gig).permit(:name, :description, :budget, :startdate, :duration, :location, :open, :hired )
 end


end
```

Feel it might help if I add my schema?

```html
  create_table "gigs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "budget"
    t.date     "startdate"
    t.integer  "duration"
    t.string   "location"
    t.boolean  "open",        default: true
    t.integer  "hired"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_gigs_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_gigs_on_user_id"
  end
```

Adding Gig model as well

```html
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :proposals
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to  :category
 has_many :abilities
 has_many :skills, through: :abilities
end
```

Comment: It's likely that you have some failing validations - please post the `Gig` model code, too.

Comment: Hi Eugen, I have added the gig model

Comment: Change your code from `@gig.save`to `@gig.save!` in GigsController#create. You'll then see the validation errors in your console output.

Comment: *Grinning like a happy kid. 
@AndréMeier I now know what the problem is, it says "user must exist, category must exist" Guess I panicked too early... thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. You should mark Alejandro Montillas answer as correct, since he gives you the correct debugging hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the validation, you can check this by doing:

Frist, go to your rails app directory and execute:

```
rails console
```

Next, create a new gig instance:

```
g = Gig.new(name: "Perry Dillard", budget: "500") #Add all the fields
```

Test if any validation fails

```
g.valid?
```

if this return false, you have some validation that is stopping the save. To se what is the problem:

```
g.errors.messages
```

This should give you the message of the validation.

Comment: Same could be accomplished by using Gig#save! instead of Gig#save. Gig#save! will enforce validations and raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid on failing validations. See http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/save%21 for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I was using `g.valid?`

Comment: @alejandor-montilla Sorry for the confusion: Your solution is completely ok, I just wanted to point out that the hashbanged `save`-method throws validation errors automatically

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to save the record, but is failing some validations.
You should check Ruby on Rails Guides for [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview).
Also you could try printing `@gig.errors` to see whats failing.

Comment: After viewing your model definition it is quite posible that the error occurs due to empty associations. Ruby on Rails 5 does presence validation on al associations by default. See [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) `optional` parameter