# 1 error prohibited this book from being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been facing problem while creating new book.
User is logged in but still it says:

1 error prohibited this book from being saved

- User must exist

When i edit my book it works fine but when i try to create new book it shows .error/

This is book controller:

```
    class BooksController < ApplicationController
     before_action :find_book, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @books = Book.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end


  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @book.update(book_params)
        redirect_to @book
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
def destroy
@book.destroy
redirect_to root_path, notice: "successfully deleted"
end

def new
    @book =Book.new

end

def create
    @book =Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
        redirect_to @book
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def find_book
    @book=Book.find(params[:id])
end

    def book_params
       params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :image)
    end
end
```

My books.rb is:

```
 class Book < ApplicationRecord
  #Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16'
   has_attached_file :image, styles: { }
   do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
  #validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: You migth try to find out the cause of the error, with something like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42629794/6780663

Comment: Where's the code? How can we help?

Comment: It looks like your `book` model has an `user_id` on it, make sure the `user` is being set on the `book`. More code would be very useful to properly answer your question!

Comment: @Ursus  i have edited my question hope this will be understandable

Comment: @Gabriel Lett  i have edited my question hope this will be understandable

Answer (score 11):

You have a `belongs_to :user` but user is not set on the Book when you save it.

you can do this:

```
belongs_to :user, :optional => true
```

or you can do this:

```
@user.books.save
```

don't do this

```
@book = Book.new
@book.save           # No user provided.
```

And, if you're using a mass assignment, be sure you can set `:user_id` or `:user` in the book_params as OK to submit in mass assignment.

Comment: please, prefer `optional: true`, `required` is deprecated